# How to network VScode dev containers together

Tags: firebase, docker, visual-studio-code, firebase-tools, vscode-remote

I'm setting up a dev container that contains firebase emulators (see below). I'm trying to access the emulators from another dev container.

Once I get my emulator container up and running (along with the emulators) I try and connect from code container to emulator container but I'm unable to reach or even ping port 9199 on my emulator container.

Is there something I'm missing when it comes to connecting these containers together?

```
##Dockerfile

FROM node:16

ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src
# Install OpenJDK-11
RUN echo 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list


# RUN apt-get update
# RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jre-headless
# RUN apt-get clean

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jre-headless && \
    apt-get clean;
RUN npm i -g firebase-tools typescript
RUN firebase --version

EXPOSE 9199

## devcontainer.json

{
    "name": "Node.js & TypeScript",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        
        // Update 'VARIANT' to pick a Node version: 18, 16, 14.
        // Append -bullseye or -buster to pin to an OS version.
        // Use -bullseye variants on local on arm64/Apple Silicon.
        "args": { 
            "VARIANT": "16-bullseye"
        }
    },
    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    "forwardPorts": [9199],

    // Configure tool-specific properties.
    "customizations": {
        // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
        "vscode": {
            // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
            "extensions": [
                "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
            ]
        }
    },

    "features": {
        "docker-from-docker": "latest"
    }
}
```